# Why wouldn't a stock sell below the bid-ask spread?

Tags: day-trading, bid-ask, after-hours-trading

In the TD Ameritrade cellphone app and in the browser site (I tried both) in post market after hours, I can't seem to sell Facebook at $261.06 a share even though the bid is 261.30 and the ask was 261.80. There is 20 million in volume. It's set to GTC and FIFO. What am I missing here?

Comment: Assuming that you have approval to trade during after hours and that you placed the order correctly then an order to sell below the bid should be executed.

Comment: After hours orders execute next day when the markets open.

Comment: No, I finally got it to execute after hours.

Comment: @Bob Baerker Right but I want to know what I was doing wrong because I finally got it to execute at 261.80 by changing it to GTC extended. I guess TdAmeritrade might have some technical situations that I don't know about?  I wish if there was a problem, TdAmeritrade had a popup service that would give the trader\investor possible reasons.

Comment: @Dheer - After hours trading in the US is from 4 to 8 PM EST.  Orders placed during the after market will execute in the after market if there's a counterparty willing to take the other side at your price.  Some brokers do not offer after hours trading.  For those that do, some  require approval to participate.

Comment: @Lowbrow - Is there any chance that your initial order did not include the 'extended' designation thereby making it ineligible to trade during after hours?

Comment: @Bob Baerker Idk, You mean the initial order made before the market closed? It didn't start as an ext order. Not thoroughly knowing the rules and technicalities could cost one a lot of $ although in this situation , I made a little money just by luck.

Comment: In your question you stated that you tried to sell your stock in post market after hours using both  the TD Ameritrade cellphone app the browser site and the order wouldn't transact.  If the order didn't execute then  I can think of only two reasons why the order failed.  1) You don't have after hours approval to trade or 2) TD requires that you designate the order for extended trading.  Other than that, I have nothing to offer. An order to sell below the current bid that is created correctly and routed properly should execute.

Comment: I just didn't put ext. That's what it was. I just figured they would figure out what the time was. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your comments that you changed your order type from GTC to GTC_EXT and it worked.
GTC_EXT stands for Good Till Cancelled Extended hours. Yes so you need this in order for your orders to fulfill after hours.

Answer (score 0):

On TD Ameritrade, an order submitted as GTC (Good Till Canceled) will not execute during after-hours trading; it can only execute while the market is officially open (usually during the hours of 9:30 am to 4:00 pm, US Eastern time, on weekdays).

To get an order to execute during after-hours trading, you can submit it as GTC + Ext (Good Till Canceled, with extended hours).